# Simultaneously download a file and update a database using jQuery Ajax

Tags: html, jquery

I have a link which is supposed to download a file, whilst simultaneously sending data to a PHP script via Ajax to update a database. The HTML for the link is:

```
<a class="rel_link" href="document.docx">Download</a>
```

And the jquery code is:

```
$("#downloadtable a").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
            url: "download.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {dlname: dlname, dlaccount: dlaccount, dlmodule: dlmodule, dlemail: dlemail, dlsub: dlsub, dlpath: dlpath},
            success: function(data){
             $("#die2").detach();
            }

         });
 });
```

Unfortunately the two don't seem to work simultaneously. If the jQuery is disabled, the document downloads perfectly. If the jQuery is enabled and the href attribute is set to `href="#"', the jQuery works and the data is written to the database. However, if jQuery is enabled and the href is set to`href="document.docx"`, the file downloads but the data does not get passed to the database. The only error message I'm getting on the console is:

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document: "http://www.mysite.org.uk/downloads/document.docx".
```

Can anyone shed any light on how to simultaneously download a document and write to the database via Ajax?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you switch the href to point to a php, you problem might be solved.
Then you can write into database, and initiate the download with the appropriate header() calls.

Look on Example#1:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php